# Передача значений из динамических input'ов

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Всех приветствую.

[Допустим, есть такой скрипт](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/)

Необходимо передать все значения из динамических input'ов в php-обработчик.

Допустим, такой код передачи:

```
$("#sendButton").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "handler.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
           // Необходимо передать все параметры из динамических input'ов
        },
        success: function() {
            alert("Успешно передано");
        }
    });
)};
```

Заранее спасибо, прошу прощения за нубство.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var send_data = [];

$('input.p_scnt').each(function() {
    send_data.push(this.value);
});

$("#sendButton").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "handler.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'inputs':send_data},
        success: function() {
            alert("Успешно передано");
        }
    });
)};
```

Comment: Эх, опять меня опередили )) и похоже у вас ответ более правильный )

Comment: @IVsevolod у нас совершенно разные решения! У вас более правильный, т.к. у автора каждое поле имеет уникальное имя.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю перед ajax обработать все input и записать их в массив, например так:

```
var d = {};
$("input").each(function(ind){
    var obj = $(this);
    d[obj.attr('name')] = obj.val();
});
```

и дальше в **data** записывать этот массив

```
$("#sendButton").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "handler.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: d,
        success: function() {
            alert("Успешно передано");
        }
    });
)};
```